Rigid body motion (RBM) transformation of interface points between a rigid and an elastic bodies



Above are pictures of a problem in mechanics. An elastic body occupying domain $\Omega$ is supported below with a fixed support and from above with a rigid body. The following calculations aim to express the movements of the points located at the interface $\Gamma_F$ between the rigid and elastic bodies in terms of a reference point $B$:
I don't understand them well, so I will explain my understanding (not sure it's correct), and confusion.
$\vec{y}(x) = \vec{x} + \vec{u}(x)$
The new position $\vec{y}$ of a point is equal to its original position $\vec{x}$ plus its displacement $\vec{u}$.
Rigid body motion transformation:
$\vec{y}(\vec{x}) = \vec{y}^B + \mathcal{R}(\beta) (\vec{x} - \vec{x}^B)$, where $\vec{x} \in \Gamma_F$
where $\mathcal{R}$ is the rotation matrix as the rigid body rotates at an angle $\beta$.
$\mathcal{R} = \begin{bmatrix}
cos(\beta) & sin(\beta)\\
-sin(\beta) & cos(\beta)
\end{bmatrix}$
Linearization for small deformation:
$\vec{u}(x) - \vec{u}^B = \vec{y} - \vec{y}^B - (\vec{x} - \vec{x}^B)\\
= (\mathcal{R}(\beta) - I)(\vec{x}-\vec{x}^B)$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.
For linearization we take,
$\mathcal{R} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & \beta\\
-\beta & 0
\end{bmatrix}$
$\Rightarrow \vec{u}(x)\mid_{\Gamma_F} = \vec{u}^B + (\mathcal{R}(\beta) - I)(\vec{x}-\vec{x}^B)$
I don't understand how the displacement of the points on the interface are parameterized by the displacement of a reference point that is also located on the interface undergoing transformation as well (rotation and translation).
Isn't a reference point supposed to be fixed?

Can you explain why you are working under the assumption that the reference point cannot have a displacement? This is basically a 2D rigid body motion which includes $x$ and $y$ translations and an in-plane rotation. So, you can always just specify the displacement of one point on the object and then a rotation about that point.

In the calculations, the reference point can have displacement. But I don't understand why this point is taken as a reference because it is also undergoing rotation and translation and it is not fixed with respect to the points at the interface of contact between the elastic and rigid bodies.

The choice of reference point is arbitrary. You can choose any point as the reference point. There is nothing special about point B, and the reference point need not be fixed.

Ah, ok. Thanks.

If Ω is an elastic body, then the rigid body has 3 DOF in the plane. It can tilt as shown, it can move up and down and it can move side to side. Any of these responses are possible from the application of a single offset force. So trying to derive the kinematics of the situation requires assumptions about the elastic body. Can you elaborate?

Thanks. The only assumptions are that the elastic body is fixed from below using the fixed support and that the upper boundary of it is attached to the rigid body, and only small displacement are taken into consideration.

The force $~\vec F~$ at point B has two components $~F_x~,F_y~$
, you can transfer this force to the center of mass , point C, additional you obtain a torque.
thus, the CM will postpones towards x direction  with $~u_x~$ and towards the  -y direction. with $~v_y~$

$$\left(\vec P_B\right)_f=  
\,\left(\vec P_B\right)_i+\begin{bmatrix}
  u_x \\
  v_y \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
the torque at the CM caused the  configuration to  rotate

form here the position vector $~\vec P_B~$ is
$$\left(\vec P_B\right)_f=  \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \beta \right) &-\sin \left( 
\beta \right) &0\\ \sin \left( \beta \right) &\cos
 \left( \beta \right) &0\\ 0&0&1\end {array}
 \right]
\,\left(\vec P_B\right)_i+\begin{bmatrix}
  u_x \\
  v_y \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $~i~$ is the initial state and $~f~$ the final state
